# Error in redaction with iText 5: "The color depth 1 is not supported." exception when apply redaction on pdf which contain image also

Tags: java, itext

Used version: itextpdf-5.5.9 and iText-extra-5.5.9

```
Exception trace:
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.UnsupportedPdfException: The color depth 1 is not supported.
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpRenderListener.renderImage(PdfCleanUpRenderListener.java:85)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor$ImageXObjectDoHandler.handleXObject(PdfContentStreamProcessor.java:967)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.displayXObject(PdfContentStreamProcessor.java:314)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.access$5000(PdfContentStreamProcessor.java:60)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor$Do.invoke(PdfContentStreamProcessor.java:913)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpContentOperator.invoke(PdfCleanUpContentOperator.java:75)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.invokeOperator(PdfContentStreamProcessor.java:248)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfContentStreamProcessor.processContent(PdfContentStreamProcessor.java:354)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpProcessor.cleanUpPage(PdfCleanUpProcessor.java:78)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpProcessor.cleanUp(PdfCleanUpProcessor.java:53)
at com.capsilon.katalyst.packager.util.StampingUtil.drawRedaction(StampingUtil.java:371)
at com.capsilon.katalyst.packager.util.PageUtil.getPages(PageUtil.java:278)
at com.capsilon.katalyst.packager.util.PageUtil.getPages(PageUtil.java:132)
at com.capsilon.katalyst.packager.delivery.DeliveryPackager.fetchPages(DeliveryPackager.java:482)
at com.capsilon.katalyst.packager.delivery.DeliveryPackager.doPDFPackaging(DeliveryPackager.java:188)
at com.capsilon.katalyst.packager.delivery.handler.EmailDeliveryRequestProcessor.doProcessing(EmailDeliveryRequestProcessor.java:42)
at com.capsilon.katalyst.packager.delivery.StandardPackagingTask.doDeliveryPackagingRequestProcessing(StandardPackagingTask.java:100)
at com.capsilon.katalyst.packager.delivery.DeliveryPackagerRequestListener.processMessage(DeliveryPackagerRequestListener.java:80)
at com.capsilon.commons.jms.MessageListener.run(MessageListener.java:157)
Caused by: com.itextpdf.text.exceptions.UnsupportedPdfException: The color depth 1 is not supported.
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfImageObject.decodeImageBytes(PdfImageObject.java:315)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfImageObject.<init>(PdfImageObject.java:200)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.PdfImageObject.<init>(PdfImageObject.java:169)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.ImageRenderInfo.prepareImageObject(ImageRenderInfo.java:124)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.parser.ImageRenderInfo.getImage(ImageRenderInfo.java:114)
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.pdfcleanup.PdfCleanUpRenderListener.renderImage(PdfCleanUpRenderListener.java:63)
```

"Code which i used for redaction using itext-xtra Plese find Below "
 i am tring to create redaction over PDF using "PdfCleanUpProcessor"

```
                List<PdfCleanUpLocation> cleanUpLocations = new ArrayList<PdfCleanUpLocation>();
                try
                {
                    for (Annotation annotation : annotationList)
                    {

                            HashMap<String, String> rotateCoordinates = rotateCoordinatesRedaction(pdfReader, annotation, (orientation <= 360) ? (360 - orientation): (orientation -360), actualPageRotation);
                            rectangle = getRectangle(rotateCoordinates);
                            cleanUpLocations.add(new PdfCleanUpLocation(page, rectangle, BaseColor.BLACK));
                        }

                    PdfCleanUpProcessor cleaner = new PdfCleanUpProcessor(cleanUpLocations, pdfStamper);
                    cleaner.cleanUp();
```

Comment: Show us your code and share your pdf

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse, Could you please help me how to share pdf with you

Comment: Just put it on Dropbox or whatever file sharing service you prefer and make sure that the file is publicly accessible.

Comment: Simply put, though: To apply redaction to embedded bitmap images, iText needs to understand the respective bitmap image format and know how to manipulate it. There is only a limited set of image formats iText understands well enough for this. Seemingly your PDF contains a bitmap in a position where redaction needs to be applied which iText does not understand well enough: "The color depth 1 is not supported." There are better ways to cope with that than such an exception, though...

Comment: @mkl , Is there any solution for issue

Comment: @MayankPandey Without the PDF in question I have no idea

Comment: @mkl and Amedee Please find PDF here:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B42NqA5UnXMVbkhQQk9tR2hpSUE/view?pref=2&pli=1

Comment: @AmedeeVanGasse  Have you find any solution for this

Comment: @mkl Have you find any solution for this

Comment: I'll have a look at the start of next week.

Comment: Hi - have you ever found a solution on this?

Answer (score 1):

A work-around for this issue has been added to iText 5.5.11: iText still does not explicitly support the type of image come across here but `PdfCleanUp` now has a better way to deal with not explicitly supported images, instead of throwing an exception it now either removes them completely or keeps them as is, depending on whether they intersect redaction zones or not.

This fix has been added in commit bd9d610fb2d77de0ee98de97d3a2911f22d42b29 on 2017-02-16 13:43:12 with the comment *"clean up now deals with unsupported images by ignoring them or deleting them entirely. No exceptions are being thrown anymore if an unsupported image is encountered."*

Of course this is no real fix. A real fix would require iText to implement at least some degree of support for all image formats allowed in PDFs, but that is not to be expected in a product in mere maintenance mode.

(In iText 7 I would eventually expect a real fix. It might require a paying customer asking for the fix, though, to give that fix some priority...)